# Problem printing a web Browser in MS Access Form, displaying a QR code

Tags: ms-access, google-api, qr-code

I use a WebBrowser within a MS Access Form.
The WepBrowser is displaying a QR code using chart.googleapis.
The “Display when” property is set to “Always”.
When I try to Print the form, or via the print preview, the QR Code is not visible.
One solution would be to display somehow the URL image to an “Image” element, but this would require to download the picture from the URL. The same Access runs in multiple PC so I would have to customize paths, etc.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `CurrentProject.Path` to pull folder location of db file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my function `UrlContent` in a query as found in my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl):

```vb
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
    
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
    
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
    
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
        
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
    
    UrlContent = Result
    
End Function
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: i am not so experienced, although i try to get improved. I understand the way it works, but i dont have a table containing the Url's. Url is generated based on a unique number (key) "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=" & [TableField] & "&chs=200x200&cht=qr" . What modification should i do?

Comment: In the picture, you can see the full URL I used - very similar to yours. So, all you need is to prefix your generated key with `https://` to obtain the full and finished URL: `"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=" & [TableField] & "&chs=200x200&cht=qr"`. For example, if _TableField holds `12345`: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=12345&chs=200x200&cht=qr".

Comment: On "Internet" function - VBA code, i have to declate that Url equals "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=" & [TableField] & "&chs=200x200&cht=qr" ? Currently, i just use the above link with table name on control sourse on wepbrowser

Comment: Yes, change that. You only need a plain picture control, not a webbrowser. Carefully read the in-line comments for the function above. Also, study the demo you can download at [GitHub](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl/tree/master/demos).

Comment: Finally , it was easier thanks to your detailed work. Thank you

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.